# How to Show UISwitch when UIStepper incremented value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch, uistepper

i want to do a task about when a UIStepper is Clicked and incremented to 1. then a Switch should appear, when ever UIStepper is clicked again, another switch should display below the first switch.

i need to display at-least 5 switches vertically when ever the UIStepper incremented.

```
-(void)onstepperClicked:(UIStepper*)selectedComponent {
if (selectedComponent == self.mainStepper) {
    if (self.mainStepper.value >=0) {
           float y=20;
        //output label
        self.outputLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)self.mainStepper.value ];
        // slider animated with stepper
        [self.mainSlider setValue:self.mainStepper.value animated:YES];
        //switch
        self.repeatingSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
        self.repeatingSwitch.frame=CGRectMake(20,y+50,100, 100);
        [self.view addSubview:self.repeatingSwitch];
        self.repeatingSwitch.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
        self.repeatingSwitch.onTintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        self.repeatingSwitch.thumbTintColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your try code.

Comment: Everytime you click the stepper use `[myView addSubview: newSwitch];` You can use autolayout to position them where you want.

Comment: i posted my try code. please check it out.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: my problem is new switch is creating but the Y axis position is not changing.

Comment: Instead this you can use stack view. So, that no need to set Y axis position.

Comment: i'm a  beginner student learning IOS app development. i have to do task by using switch and stepper concepts only.

Comment: In your code above change `float y=20` to `float y = self.mainstepper.value * 20`. You may have to tweak that 20 to make it look ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIStackView. It automatically takes care of the constraints of the child elements for you. Refer

- https://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro
- https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i have to do with only stepper , switch, slider only.

Comment: `UIStackView` is introduced with iOS 9.0 SDK. So you cannot use StackView for those apps which are using iOS SDK less than 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Design a Custom cell in a nib with a single `UISwitch` inside.
Then set a `UITableView` below the `UIStepper` and load cells which you have designed.

When ever you click on `UIStepper` just increase the number of rows in `UITableViewDataSource` method.